# Projective resolutions of modules over a valuation ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be the field of [Hahn series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series#Formulation) in an indeterminate $t$ with exponents in $\mathbb{R}$, coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and valuation $v$. For each $q\in\mathbb{R}$, we set $$I_q:=\{a\in K:v(a)\geq q\},$$ $$I_{>q}:=\{a\in K:v(a)>q\}$$ and $A:=I_0$. I am new to projective resolutions and want to find them for some simple cases of $A$-modules. It is clear that $$0\to A\to A\to 0$$ is a proj. res. for $A$ and that $$0\to I_q\to A\to A/I_q\to 0$$ is a proj. res. for $A/I_q$ for each $q>0$. I am now trying to find a proj. res. for $A/I_{>q}$, ($q\geq 0$), but the non-principal ideals make things tricky.

For example, $$0\to I_{>q}\to A\to A/I_{>q}\to 0$$ is not a projective resolution since $I_{>q}$ is not projective. **What is a way around this?**

Since $A$ is local, an $A$-module is projective iff free i.e. a direct sum of copies of $A$. To find a proj. res. for $K$, I presumably need some epimorphism $\alpha:\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty A\to K$ and need to be able to find $\text{ker}(\alpha)$, but with all such morphisms I find, I cannot find the kernel. Similarly for $I_{>0}$.

Is there a good way of finding such resolutions?

Comment: Do you have some reason to expect a simple projective resolution to exist?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have been asked to try to find such resolutions and do not know what to expect, I've never tried to find any kind of resolution before

Comment: So it basically amounts to finding the projective dimension of $I_{>0}$. This ideal isn’t projective: any two elements have an $A$-linear relation, so it would be of rank $\leq 1$ – yet it’s not finitely generated. But can’t you find a system of generators with an easy description of the relations?

Comment: @Aphelli $I_{>0}$ is generated by $\{t^q:q>0\}$, where $t^q=t^pt^{q-p}$ for $0<p\leq q$, but how does help find the projective dimension?

Comment: Can you say something about the module of relations?

Comment: See [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994637) for a general way to construct resolutions of ideals in valuation rings.

Comment: @Aphelli So $I_{>0}$ is generated by $\{t^{2^{-n}}:n\geq 0\}$ with $t^{2^{-n}}=t^{2^{-n-1}}t^{2^{-n-1}}$ for each $n$. Then we can form epimorphism $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A\to I_{>0}$ and the kernel of this is the submodule of generated by $t^{2^{-n}}+t^{2^{-n-1}}t^{2^{-n-1}}$, $n\geq 0$. Then the free module generated by these generators is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A$.... am I on the right track?

Comment: Looks like it will end up with $\cdots\to\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A\to\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A\to I_{>0}\to 0$ i.e. infinite projective dimension but I think it will quickly get messy

Comment: Why infinite dimension? Can you find a relation between the relations (if that makes sense)?